# how to resolve the below error which i received while trying to convert the reactjs app to apk using bubblewrap

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to convert an react app into android app using bubblewrap
i got below error while doing so.

Any help will be appreciate.

I am doing this for the first time and i had used https://vaadin.com/blog/submitting-a-pwa-to-google-play-store-using-bubblewrap for the reference

"
cli ERROR Command failed: gradlew.bat assembleRelease --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

"

[image]